# binary search over function arguments with/without boost

Tags: c++, boost, c++03

Given the:

```
typedef .../*some type*/ SomeValue;

SomeValue someFunction(int arg){
     return /*some calculation involving arg that produces SomeValue*/
}

int firstCandidate = 0, lastCandidate = 101;
SomeValue desiredValue = SomeValue();
```

I want to find `int` argument which produces `desiredValue`(when passed to `someFunction`) using binary search (`std::lower_bound`).
`firstCandidate`, `lastCandidate` are parameters to be given to `someFunction`.
For search candidates `std::lower_bound` should call `someFunction(currentArgument)` and compare result with `desiredValue`. for `SomeValue` `someFunction(x) < someFunction(x + 1)` is true.

I.e. it should produce same result as this:

```
int findArgLowerbound(int first, int last, SomeValue refVal){
     for (int i = first; i < last; i++){
          if (someFunction(i) >= refVal)
               return i;
     }
     return last;
}
```

only using standard functions + binary search algorithm.

How can I do that *EASILY* (without writing my own binary search function) with and without boost?
`int` is not iterator, and I haven't figured out how to make `boost::make_transform_iterator` in this case.

**restrictions**:

1. c++03 standard.
2. boost is okay, but I'd *really* prefer solution without it.

--edit--

I want to know how can I use built-in or already-available functions (std::lower_bound and similar) do what I want. I *could* write specialized binary search function, but I don't think that'll be the "right" way to do it.

Comment: http://code-generator.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Already solved it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out (enjoy the macro+template voodoo).

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/typeof/std/utility.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <sstream>

std::string convertArgs(int arg1, int arg2){
    std::stringstream out;
    out << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << arg1*arg2;
    return out.str();
}

void boostTest(){
    int first = 0, last = 42;
    int arg = 2;
    std::string desiredValue = "00000007";
    BOOST_AUTO(range, boost::irange(first, last));
    BOOST_AUTO(start, boost::make_transform_iterator(range.begin(), std::bind1st(std::ptr_fun(convertArgs), arg)));
    BOOST_AUTO(end, boost::make_transform_iterator(range.end(), std::bind1st(std::ptr_fun(convertArgs), arg)));
    BOOST_AUTO(found, std::lower_bound(start, end, desiredValue));
    if (found != end){
        std::cout << "str:" << *found << "\nval: " << *(found.base());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    boostTest();
    return 0;
}
```

Most likely, can't be done **easily** without boost unless you generate arrays with all possible values, make wrapper iterators yourself or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach it:

Pretend you have a `vector<SomeValue>` that is sorted. This vector is accessible using `someFunction(index)`.

Now, [look at this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search#algorithm). That is pseudocode for the binary search. Continuing with the thought process above, replace `A[imid]` with `someFunction(imid)` and make `key` a `SomeValue`. Make sure `SomeValue` has a valid `operator <` (or a comparator function that you use in place of it).

This will of course only work if `someFunction(x) < someFunction(x + 1)` for all `x`. You have stated this to be true, so it should be good.

I would suggest using the iterative approach because both have the same asymptotic runtime, and the iterative version makes it easier to report a key that was not found, and tends to use less memory.

**EDIT** I am unaware of a simple way to do it using the `std` stuff. As you mentioned above, `int` wouldn't work as an iterator, and all of the functions that you would probably want to use take iterators. *Technically* though, the iterators in these functions are templated types, so you write your own `IntIter` class or something like that. Using `std::lower_bound` would need the `operator *()`, `operator ++()`, and `operator +(int)`. `operator *()` would probably return `someFunction(n)`, where `n` is the int value associated with the `IntIter`. However, ***I don't know if this would actually work***, and it would probably take more time and coding. You should look at [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) and [`std::advance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/) (called in `lower_bound`) if you want to take this approach.

Comment: I've asked how can I use built-in functions (std::lower_bound and similar) instead of writing my own specialized function. I can write customized binary search function myself, but this isn't exactly "right" way to do it.

Comment: @SigTerm added my edit. I'm not sure of a straightforward way to do this with `std` since you don't have a container/iterator. What I originally posted was the solution that seemed simplest to me with what you have